# Finding the PDE and replicating strategy of a european contigent claim

Tags: black-scholes, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion, martingale, black-scholes-pde

Suppose that we have the Black and Scholes model where the interest rate and the volatility are time varying:

$dB(t)=r(t)B(t)dt$ and

$dS(t)=S(t)b(t)dt+S(t)\sigma(t)dW(t), S(0)=s>0$

where $r,b,\sigma$ deterministic, positive and bounded.

I know that the price of european call option with strike price $K$ is given by

$\tilde{V}(t)=U(t,S(t))$ and

$U(t,S(t)=\tilde{E}[max[S(0)e^{\int_t^T \sigma(s)d\tilde{W}(s)-\dfrac{1}{2}\int_t^T \sigma^2(s)ds}-Ke^{-\int_t^T r(s)ds}],0]$

where $\tilde{E}$ the expected value under the new probability measure $\tilde{P}$ and $\tilde{W}$ is a wiener process. $S(t)$ here is the discounted price of the stock.

Can someone help me how to find the PDE and the replicating strategy of the european call option?

Comment: Have a look [here](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/12788/self-financing-and-black-scholes-merton-formula?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: Yes, it is what I was looking for. Thank you guys